# Univariate Kernel in Gaussian Process

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, radial-basis-functions

I cant seem to get my head around the behaviour of different kernels in an univariate case when using a gaussian process regressor.

For example, this is the RBF kernel: $$K(x, x')= exp( - \frac{ ||x-x'||^2 }{ 2\sigma^2 })$$
In the univariate case $x' = x$, so the kernel becomes $K(x, x)=exp( -\frac{ ||x-x||^2 }{ 2\sigma^2 })$ which resolves to $K(x,x) = e^0$

So from what I know right now, every kernel function yields $1$ for every given value and still, changing the kernel parameters for a kernel changes the outcome of the prediction when using the gaussian process regressor.

I've tried this with scikit-learns GP implementation, using various kernels. Every kernel has the euclidean distance term in its exponent so it should result to 1 in the univariate case. But still, messing around with the various kernel parameters, changes the quality of the learned model.

Please enlighten me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single univariate, $x'$ need not be equal to $x$.

For example you can have $0$ and $1$ and $$K(0,1)=\exp\left(-\frac1{2\sigma^2} \right)$$

Changing $\sigma$ would change the kernel value.

Comment: So this would be the case if I've trained for, lets say, $t=0$ and $t=2$ and wanted to predict a value for $t=1$ afterwards? So x and x' are not distinct features/channels/etc but values on the x-axis?

Comment: yes, they are two points consisting of the same feature but they can of course take distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
K(x,x') = \sigma^2\exp\left(\frac{||x-x'||^2}{2l^2}\right)
\end{align*}

This formula is applied to all pairwise combinations of your $x$ input. So the Kernel returns an $N$ dimensional matrix. The RBF Kernel, $K(x,x')$ does in fact resolve to $e^0$, but only for the diagonal terms in the matrix where $x_i = x'_i$. For other cases you will get back an answer not equal to one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).